# How can i run my reactjs appication just by doubble clicking in the index.html of build

Tags: reactjs

I have my complete project and production build also.

I just wants to run it by doubble clicking the index.html file

```
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
            <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <title>React App</title>
            <link href="./static/css/main.e6ec6509.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>

        <body>
            <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
            <div id="root"></div>
            <script>
                ! function(c) {
                    function e(e) {
                        for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], a = 0, i = []; a < n.length; a++) t = n[a], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, t) && s[t] && i.push(s[t][0]), s[t] = 0;
                        for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (c[r] = o[r]);
                        for (d && d(e); i.length;) i.shift()();
                        return f.push.apply(f, u || []), l()
                    }

                    function l() {
                        for (var e, r = 0; r < f.length; r++) {
                            for (var t = f[r], n = !0, o = 1; o < t.length; o++) {
                                var u = t[o];
                                0 !== s[u] && (n = !1)
                            }
                            n && (f.splice(r--, 1), e = p(p.s = t[0]))
                        }
                        return e
                    }
                    var t = {},
                        s = {
                            1: 0
                        },
                        f = [];

                    function p(e) {
                        if (t[e]) return t[e].exports;
                        var r = t[e] = {
                            i: e,
                            l: !1,
                            exports: {}
                        };
                        return c[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, p), r.l = !0, r.exports
                    }
                    p.e = function(o) {
                        var e = [],
                            t = s[o];
                        if (0 !== t)
                            if (t) e.push(t[2]);
                            else {
                                var r = new Promise(function(e, r) {
                                    t = s[o] = [e, r]
                                });
                                e.push(t[2] = r);
                                var n, u = document.createElement("script");
                                u.charset = "utf-8", u.timeout = 120, p.nc && u.setAttribute("nonce", p.nc), u.src = p.p + "./static/js/" + ({}[o] || o) + "." + {
                                    3: "5a2546a4",
                                    4: "3a02c486",
                                    5: "ed3359dd",
                                    6: "27ea97b0"
                                }[o] + ".chunk.js";
                                var a = new Error;
                                n = function(e) {
                                    u.onerror = u.onload = null, clearTimeout(i);
                                    var r = s[o];
                                    if (0 !== r) {
                                        if (r) {
                                            var t = e && ("load" === e.type ? "missing" : e.type),
                                                n = e && e.target && e.target.src;
                                            a.message = "Loading chunk " + o + " failed.\n(" + t + ": " + n + ")", a.name = "ChunkLoadError", a.type = t, a.request = n, r[1](a)
                                        }
                                        s[o] = void 0
                                    }
                                };
                                var i = setTimeout(function() {
                                    n({
                                        type: "timeout",
                                        target: u
                                    })
                                }, 12e4);
                                u.onerror = u.onload = n, document.head.appendChild(u)
                            }
                        return Promise.all(e)
                    }, p.m = c, p.c = t, p.d = function(e, r, t) {
                        p.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, {
                            enumerable: !0,
                            get: t
                        })
                    }, p.r = function(e) {
                        "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
                            value: "Module"
                        }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
                            value: !0
                        })
                    }, p.t = function(r, e) {
                        if (1 & e && (r = p(r)), 8 & e) return r;
                        if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule) return r;
                        var t = Object.create(null);
                        if (p.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", {
                                enumerable: !0,
                                value: r
                            }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof r)
                            for (var n in r) p.d(t, n, function(e) {
                                return r[e]
                            }.bind(null, n));
                        return t
                    }, p.n = function(e) {
                        var r = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
                            return e.default
                        } : function() {
                            return e
                        };
                        return p.d(r, "a", r), r
                    }, p.o = function(e, r) {
                        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)
                    }, p.p = "/", p.oe = function(e) {
                        throw console.error(e), e
                    };
                    var r = this.webpackJsonprussia = this.webpackJsonprussia || [],
                        n = r.push.bind(r);
                    r.push = e, r = r.slice();
                    for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) e(r[o]);
                    var d = n;
                    l()
                }([])
            </script>
            <script src="./static/js/2.14ee151b.chunk.js"></script>
            <script src="./static/js/main.c9f1fb9d.chunk.js"></script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

Above is my **index.html**

I found something from stackoverflow that we can do that by putting only **build.js** in **script src inside index.html**.

But how we can get **build.js**

When i am running **npm run build** it is giving me **chunks.js and chunks.css**

Can't find **build.js**

Please have a  look.

Comment: It sounds odd that you know about production builds, but not that you need to serve your web page using an http(s) server for the browser to run things normally. Loading it from file:/// comes with a ton of security restrictions. So: you don't run webpages by double clicking index.html - you start an http server and then you load your page using a localhost URL.

Comment: I wants to run it without internet connection. It is for client . he is not a developer

Comment: Security doesn't matter my case. Just need to run anyway thats client wants

Comment: I said an http-server, not "an internet connection". You can run the first without the latter. And it doesn't matter whether you don't care about security because you get no choice: browsers _don't let you run_ what you want from file:/// because that's how browsers are supposed to work. Just fire up the simplest http server (`python3 -m http.server`, [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), just pick something that fits your tools) and open `http://localhost` (probably with a port suffix because again, that's how these tools simply work)

Comment: You mean using any nginx or apache or wsgi server ?

Comment: I have no idea why you'd need any of those if you just want to see the file run. Those are all incredibly complex, configuration-heavy, lots-of-work-to-set-up-correctly http server solutions. Just use a simple zero-conf command line http server. You're already using Node, clearly, so just `npm install http-server`, add a script `"server": "http-server"` and now you can run `npm run server`.

Comment: I don't want to use terminal at all

Comment: Then yeah, you're going to have to set up a persistent server like Apache or the like, and build into whatever directory you configure that to look at. The basic rule of web dev is "you _cannot_ run or test on file:/// because that's not how browsers work". They _need_ a URL to properly run web pages.

Comment: yeah. i was thinking same . but angular can do this way. Was hoping can do it in react also